# Whenever I save my files as file type java, VS code opens .class file instead of ".java" file and .java file isn't created

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, text-editor

This happened after updating the vs code and adding latest java extension pack(By Microsoft only, not added any other extension other than that).

And here's an example of what's happening:

I'm saving my Geek file, then i'll press ctrl+s and then i'll enter class name and under field "save as: java" and then i'll save. Now the twist is it doesn't create Geek.java file instead of that it creates Geek.class file and opens it up.

I tried to delete the extension and then it solved the problem, but again installing extension... same issue came.

I even tried to delete all my extension and extension-files and re-installing them, still it didn't work.

Comment: What is your question? Are you sure you are opening the correct file? Can you show us a specific example?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The steps to reproduce need more detail, but the "question" is pretty obviously "how do I make it stop doing that?"

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Suppose I'm saving my Geek file, then i'll press ctrl+s and then i'll enter class name and under field "save as: java" and then i'll save. Now the twist is it doesn't create Geek.java file instead of that it creates Geek.class file and opens it up

Comment: Check this document please -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Okay Harif I'll improve the question

Comment: What is in Geek.class? Is it compiled bytecode or is it your Java code?

Comment: No it's blank .class file just created